# Perl trim MP3 file

Tags: perl, mp3

How to Trim MP3 file selectively from start time to end time. For example if I have 4 minutes mp3 file and I need to trim the sound of the file only between the second 140 to the second 170. If pure Perl module or a module that installs on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two modules on CPAN. `MP3::Splitter` and `MP3::Cut::Gapless`, both of which contain C-code and currently do not compile under Windows. Not totally the fault of Windows mind you, `MP3::Splitter` doesn't seem to work anywhere with recent Perls. It fails because of a broken dependency (`MPEG::Audio::Frame`), I'm looking into that, maybe I can find a fix.

In the meantime, if you use Windows 10, you can give the Linux Subsystem for Windows (WSL) a try and run your script from there.

```
use MP3::Cut::Gapless;

my $cut = MP3::Cut::Gapless->new(
    file      => 'input.mp3',
    start_ms  => 140000,
    end_ms    => 170000,
);

open my $out, '>', 'output.mp3' or die "Can't write MP3";

while ( $cut->read( my $buf, 4096 ) ) {
    syswrite $out, $buf;
}

close $out;
```

Or you can install a lightweight tool named [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows) and shell out to that

```
`ffmpeg -ss 00:02:20 -t 00:00:30 -i input.mp3 output.mp3`
```

Ok, here is an **update**.

I looked into the problem with `MPEG::Audio::Frame` and it's **just the tests that are failing**¹!

That means, you can force install `MPEG::Audio::Frame` first, then do a regular install of `MP3::Splitter`. Then you can run this script

```
use MP3::Splitter;
mp3split('yourfile.mp3', {verbose => 1}, [140, 30]);
```

You will then find your new file "01_yourfile.mp3" in the same directory as the input file. That's a clunky interface but at least it works.

¹I contacted the author. The problem is that the tests read their data from **DATA**, but the author did not use `binmode`. So under Windows that DATA gets read as text and shit goes awry.

**Final update**

I managed to get maintainership of `MPEG::Audio::Frame` and fixed the bug. The new version 0.10 is now on CPAN. Hence, with this fix, `MP3::Splitter` will install fine everywhere.